# Prevent another db query execution until a set of queries finishes

Tags: php, sqlite, codeigniter

I have function that is called via ajax from multiple browser instances.

```
public function update_counters($message)
  {

      //increment ticket counter
        $this->db->where('id', 1);
        $this->db->set('ticket', 'ticket+1', FALSE);
        $this->db->update('counter');

        //increment waiting counter
        $this->db->where('id', $message);
        $this->db->set('waiting', 'waiting+1', FALSE);
        $this->db->update('ambulance');   

        //get value from ticket counter
        $query = $this->db->get_where('counter', array('id' => 1));  

     $row = $query->row();    

        //add new row in ticket table
        $data = array(
            'ticket' => ($row->ticket),
            'ambulance' => $message
            );              

     $this->db->insert('ticket', $data); 

     //    
     return $row->ticket;

    }
```

These queries are executed one by one and work fine when the function is called less frequently. But the problem occures when more users call the function simultaneously or one user calls the function multiple times and very fast. The problem is that the first one (ticket counter) increments twice before an insert can occur. This results with 2 inserted rows that have the same value for the ticket. How can i make sure that the next increment that should be done occurs only when the previous insert was made?

Comment: Read about `TABLE LOCK` https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/lock-tables.html  also google _codeigniter and lock tables_

Answer (score 2):

Sorry, but your whole approach seems to be flawed.

**Information that changes with changes in the database, should be stored in the database only.**

You've got a table of tickets. Each ticket should have an unique number, probably the auto-increase main index of the ticket table (https://www.sqlite.org/autoinc.html).

Next you can have flags in the ticket table, like 'Waiting', 'Answered' and so on.

What you do to get information from the ticket table, is to simply count the rows with certain flags.

Alternatively you could use locks, but on a busy system this will cause delays.

I am not completely sure what you're trying to accomplish, since you don't really tell us, so my answer is based on assumptions. Something like: You need a ticket numbering system, and be able to count waiting tickets.